# Inserting an element to the end of the doubly-linked list

Tags: c, list

I'm writing a program which can insert elements to the end of the list, and display one of then. It inserts properly, but I can display the specified one.

```
typedef struct Node
{
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
        struct Node *prev;
} node;

void insert(node *head, int data)
{
        node *newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            while(head != NULL)
                head = head->next;

            head->next = newNode;
            (head->next)->prev = head;
        }
}

void print(node *head, int element)
{
    node *temp = head;
    int count = 0, i = 1;
    while(i < element)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", temp->data);
}

int main()
{
        node *start = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        start = NULL;

        int data1 = 4, data2 = 5;
        insert(start,data1);
        insert(start,data2);

        print(start, 1);
}
```

Why doesn't it work? Also, could you tell me if I am doing this properly?

Comment: Why are you setting start = NULL after you malloc'ed? That is a memory leak.

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you expect to see and what happened instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pass the `start` pointer *by value*. This means that any changes to it inside the `insert` function will be lost once the function returns.

You can pass the pointer by reference:

```
void insert(node **head, int data)
{
    /* ... */
    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = newNode;
    else
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    node *start = NULL;
    insert(&start, 1);
    /* ... */
}
```

Or return the pointer from the function:

```
node *insert(node *head, int data)
{
    /* ... */
    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    node *start = NULL;
    start = insert(start, 1);
    insert(start, 2);  /* Do not get the returned pointer, as the returned pointer no longer points to the start of the list */
    /* ... */
}
```

The problem with both these solution is that you change `head` if it's not `NULL`, to point to the node before the last node. In the loop inside `insert` you should use a temporary pointer instead.

---

As a safety precaution, you should check that you don't have a `NULL` node in the loop in the `print` function. Think about what will happen otherwise if you pass a number that is larger than the number of nodes in the list.

Comment: Your second solvage will not work, because it will dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: @ÁkosKovács Take a look at the OP's `insert` function again. He checks for `head` being `NULL`, no dereferencing of `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Now it seems to break here:             (*head)->next = newNode;
            ((*head)->next)->prev = *head;

Comment: @khernik That's because in the loop you loop until `head` becomes `NULL`. You should loop until `(*head)->next` becomes `NULL`.

Comment: @khernik I recommend you learn how to use a debugger. Then you could step through the code line by line, while checking the values of all variables and pointers. These kind of errors are very easy to find then.

Comment: Thanks, I'll research a bit on using debugger.

Comment: @Joachim: The problem with both these solution is that you change head if it's not NULL, to point to the node before the last node. In the loop inside insert you should use a temporary pointer instead.
 ..........He's re-using the head pointer, although destructively, but that wouldn't cause problems in `main`. Its just a local copy. Unless OP uses the double pointer method. :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I skipped a few lines.

Please see my revised comments inline with your code snippets for `main()`:

```
node *start = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));//You allocate memory here. Good.
start = NULL;//Memory leak. 

//Instead of the above two lines use this
node* start=NULL;

int data1 = 4, data2 = 5;
start=insert(start,data1);//If you want to do it statically, why not write insert(start,4)?
insert(start,data2);
....
```

I would suggest to add a NULL check in the `print()` function.

```
void print(node *head, int element)
{
    //Null check for the start pointer.
    //If you would have had this here, you'd have never faced such problem.
    if(head == NULL)
    {
      //Handle null
    }
    node *temp = head;
    int count = 0, i = 1;
  ....
}
```

And adding up to your `insert()` I would suggest:

```
node* insert(node *head, int data)
{
        node *newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode;
            return head;
        }
        else
        {
            while(head != NULL)
                head = head->next;

            head->next = newNode;
            (head->next)->prev = head;
            return NULL;
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick that makes things a lot easier, and also makes your code more efficient!

The trick is to use a circular list, and have the "head" node be a sentinel value. An empty list is represented by a single node that has both `prev` and `next` pointing to itself. You never need NULL, and this style greatly reduces the special-casing you need. It also gives you O(1) access to both the head and the tail of the list. The `data` field of the head is never used. It's described in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming."

In this style, you get something like this: [untested]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
   int data;
   struct Node *next, *prev;
} node;

void insert_list(node *head, int data) {
  node d = {data, head, head->prev};
  node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
  /* TODO: handle malloc failure */
  *new_node = d;
  head->prev->next = new_node;
  head->prev = new_node;
}

node *get_list(node *head, int n) {
  node *node = head;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    node = node->next;
    if (node == head) {
      /* TODO: handle out-of-bounds index */
    }
  }
  return node;
}

void print_list(node *head, int i) {
   printf("%d\n", get_list(head, i)->data);
}

node *new_list(void) {
  node *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
  /* TODO: handle malloc failure */
  head->next = head->prev = head;
  return head;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  node *list = new_list();
  insert_list(list, 10);
  insert_list(list, 20);
  print_list(list, 0);
  print_list(list, 1);
  return 0;
}
```